# How to count total occurence of checked field?

Tags: apex, formula, custom-field, roll-up-summary

I have a checkbox field called `Has_Key__c` that checks whether an employee has a key to the building or not.

I want to make a sum of all checked `Has_Key__c` and compare it with a total number of available keys. There is a field that holds this total number, called `Total_Keys__c`

I want to output `Total_Keys__c - Sum(Has_Key__c)` somewhere, preferably in a field as well.

What's the easiest way to do so? Formula? Apex? Rollup Summary?

Comment: Is there any relationship (schema-wise) between Total_Keys__c and Has_Key__c?

Comment: Martin, can you provide more of a description?  Does the Object with the Has_Key__c field have a relationship to a Parent with Total_Keys__c?  Is it a master detail relationship?  If so, you could utilize a combination of rollup summary fields and formulas to get your desired output.  

Furthermore, is this something you want displayed on the detail page of the parent, or could you simply run a summarized report on the Total_Keys__c object?

Comment: Rollup summary would be ideal, but your data has to be configured correctly. I would envision that the design would be as follows: `Building__c` is a building, `Key__c` is a key, and `Building_Key__c` is a many-to-many object (master-detail to `Building__c` and `Key__c`, and a lookup to `User`, and `Has_Key__c` field). Standard Rollups would work with this model, and a formula to express the remaining keys.

Comment: There are no relationships yet, but the feedback provides me with good information on how to implement that.

Comment: @sfdcfox If you could transform your comment to an answer, I would choose it as best answer. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with standard functionality using a roll up summary field and a formula field. This might be accomplished with three objects: `Building__c`, `Key__c`, and `Building_Key__c`. The `Building__c` would store data about each building, and `Key__c` would represent a key (e.g. serial number, etc). `Building_Key__c` would have two master-detail relationships (called a "join object"), one to `Building__c` and one to `Key__c`, with a lookup field to a `User`. From here, you can build a roll up summary that counts the number of keys that are assigned to each building, and, with a field called `Total_Keys__c` on `Building__c`, you can then calculate how many keys are left.